# ElasticSearch incremental snapshot is ambiguous

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch snapshot/restore [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) states that the index snapshot process is incremental.

Could you please explain what does it mean and confirm that every snapshot is autonomous in terms of restoration?

Use case :

Let's say I have created repository and first snapshotA containing all indexes at the moment A.

Sometime later (for example one hour later) I create new snapshotB of all the indexes at the moment B that have changed since the moment A.

There are two questions :

1. Does the size of snapshotB will be equal to the actual size of all indexes and contain all the data at the moment B or contain just the partial data : difference between snapshotA and snapshotB ?
2. If the second, how does elasticseach calculate that difference  ?
3. If the second, can we safely delete snapshotA without loosing the data for the snapshotB ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snapshots are incremental at file level, not document level.
Each shard is a Lucene index and each Lucene index is performing [automatic segments merging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) in the background. These segments are the files that are considered for a snapshot.

If at time A your index has 5 segments and by the time B 3 of them have merged into a bigger one, the snapshot taken at time B will only add this new segment in the snapshots repository. And in the metadata of the snapshot it will record that it needs this file and the 2 other files that were already added when snapshot A was created.

If you use the normal [DELETE snapshot API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) Elasticsearch will delete those files that are not needed by any other existent snapshot. In this example, ES will delete the 3 segments that were merged into the larger one. Any other option of deleting a snapshot is not recommended and could lead to data loss.